# Combining the UNIQUE and CHECK constraints

Tags: sql, constraints

I have a table with columns a b and c, and if c is false then I only want to allow insertions if columns a and b are unique, but if c is true then a and b do not need to be unique.

Example:
There can only be one (foo, bar, false) in the table, but no limit on how many (foo, bar, true) there can be.

I tried something like CONSTRAINT blah UNIQUE (a,b) AND CHECK (C is TRUE) but I can't figure out the correct syntax.

Comment: which database? mysql, oracle, postgres, ms sql, etc...

Answer (score 10):

1. Create an indexed view returning a and b with a filter `WHERE C = false`, then create a unique index on the view. This is a general approach
2. If you have SQL Server 2008, then [create a unique filtered index](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx) instead
3. Stored procedure
4. Trigger (before or after)

Comment: didn't know about filtered indexes

Answer (score 6):

Unique constraints are for all rows, and there is no way to specify only some rows.

Check constraints are only for validation within a single row.

The only ways to achieve your requirements is to do any of the following:

1) create a stored procedure where all INSERTs are made from.  You can validate all of your logic here.  However rogue programs/users can avoid using this and defeat your logic.

2) create a trigger that validates your logic and causes invalid inserts/updates to fail.  Should be written to handle a set of rows at a time

3) create a check constraint that calls a user defined function that does your validation checks.  This is considered a bad practice and should be avoided because they are very slow and may fail for multi-row updates.

I recommend option #2, trigger, because this is exactly what triggers were designed for.

Answer (score 1):

You can always create a trigger that checks the required conditions before inserting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **table constraint** (depending on SQL engine -- not clear which one you're using) to make sure there aren't too many tuples of a particular kind.

Under Firebird 2.1:

```
fb> CREATE TABLE so2587151 (
  >   a VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  >   b VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  >   c VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL CHECK (c in ('T', 'F')),
  >   CONSTRAINT so2587151_only_one_false CHECK (    -- begin CONSTRAINT
  >     NOT EXISTS (   SELECT a, b, COUNT('x')
  >                      FROM so2587151
  >                     WHERE c = 'F'
  >                  GROUP BY 1, 2
  >                    HAVING COUNT('x') >= 1  )
  >   )                                              -- end CONSTRAINT
  > );
fb> INSERT INTO so2587151(a,b,c) VALUES ('foo', 'bar', 'T');
fb> INSERT INTO so2587151(a,b,c) VALUES ('foo', 'bar', 'T');
fb> INSERT INTO so2587151(a,b,c) VALUES ('foo', 'bar', 'F');
fb> INSERT INTO so2587151(a,b,c) VALUES ('foo', 'bar', 'F');
Error: Operation violates CHECK constraint  on view or table
-Operation violates CHECK constraint SO2587151_ONLY_ONE_FALSE on view or table SO2587151
-At trigger 'CHECK_15'
fb> SELECT * FROM so2587151;
 A  |  B  | C
==============
foo | bar | T
foo | bar | T
foo | bar | F
```

As you can see from the constraint violation error message, this is implemented in terms of Firebird's trigger mechanisms under the hood.

Comment: On MS SQL, I get the following error: `Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.`