# How should I do this (business logic) in Sql Server? A constraint?

Tags: t-sql, database-design, sql-server-2008, constraints, unique

I wish to add some type of business logic constraint to a table, but not sure how / where.

I have a table with the following fields.

- ID INTEGER IDENTITY
- HubId INTEGER
- CategoryId INTEGER
- IsFeatured BIT
- Foo NVARCHAR(200)

etc.

So what i wish is that you can only have one featured thingy, per hubId + categoryId.

```
eg.
1, 1, 1, 1, 'blah'  -- Ok.
2, 1, 2, 1, 'more blah' -- Also Ok
3, 1, 1, 1, 'aaa' -- constraint error
4, 1, 1, 0, 'asdasdad' -- Ok.
5, 1, 1, 0, 'bbbb' -- Ok.

etc.
```

so the third row to be inserted would fail because that hub AND category already have a featured thingy.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587151/combining-the-unique-and-check-constraints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a database constraint to protect data. To me, business logic is calculations or complex logic or row-by-row processing: not a flavour of unique constraint

In this case:

1. you can use a trigger to check after the insert
2. define an indexed view filtering IsFeatured = 1 to on HubId, CategoryId, IsFeatured
3. use a [filtered index](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx) because you have SQL Server 2008 (which is similar to an indexed view)

I'd go for option 3, personally

PS: where is articleID you mentioned?

And this question to: [Combining the UNIQUE and CHECK constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587151)

Edit:

Basically, you'd do

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_Foo ON Mytable (HubId, CategoryId) WHERE IsFeatured = 1
```

So uniqueness is now checked on (HubId, CategoryId) ***only*** for the subset of data where IsFeatured = 1

Comment: articleId was a mistake. i've fixed it up, above. So .. a filtered index .. that sounds interesting ... brb (reads up about it).. hmmm. i think my head just poped. Can u elaborate on the filtered index? eg. is this a 'subset of data' or a 'Heterogeneous data' ? I feel so stupid :(

Comment: .. and because this is an index, i still need to have the AFTER insert (and update) trigger, right? (and index only speeds up the select query, in the trigger).

Comment: .. and what about using a Check Constraint + a filtered index? (I thought check constraints should be used over triggers, if possible)

Comment: @Pure.Krome: the index enforces the uniqueness you want by only allowing unique combinations of HubId, CategoryId where isfeatured = 1. When isfeatured = 0, it is not enforced. You **do not** need a trigger or check constraint if you use a filtered index

Comment: @gbn awesomesauce!! confirmed. Not only do i get an index (to help with query speed) but it's _ALSO_ offers constraining! Who's your Daddy??!! (and what does he do). Cheers mate!

Comment: Oh now that's a nice use for filtered indexes.